# How to set list item clicked by default when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a listview dynamically created when page loads, and I want to set the first list item to be clicked by default, how can I do that using jQuery/javascript?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Isn't List Item: `<li>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this way:

```
$(function () {
  // Give the below one, or use the perfect selector for your first <li>
  $("li").first().trigger("click");
});
```

Or if you are making it using `<select>` tag, you need to handle it in a different way:

```
$(function () {
  // Give the below one, or use the perfect selector for your first <select>
  $("select option").first().prop("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: This is the simplest. LOL.